# 3rd-party cookies and the Google Picker

Tags: google-api, google-picker

The Google Picker API currently requires the use of third-party cookies. Unfortunately, browsers have begun to block third-party cookies by default.

Are there plans for the Google API script (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) to not required the use of third-party cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Google bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188699186

Please star the ticket.

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same issue, latest chrome breaks the file picker to open.

As a workaround I have to allow all the cookies, which triggers a reload of the page, then the filepicker could be opened.